# Data display based on alphabet order text using javascript,html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have json, I am trying to sort based on alphabet order text, I attached the sample image how to look and feel.

Sample Json:

```
{
  "listData": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Audi",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "alfa Romeo",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "BMW",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Chevrolet",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Chrysler",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Dacia",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Dodge",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Daihatsu",
      "desc": "Hello World",
      "price": "55",
      "src": "01.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

So, I need to display the text like above the picture.
I think first i need to change the json format using in javascript code, then i need to implement the design.

Can anyone provide the idea, how to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide your listData array into sub-arrays. One sub-array for each letter.
To do this, you iterate through each element in listData and look at the first character at the name property. Then create a new array for that letter or add it to the already existing array for that letter.

```
var jsonData = /*YOUR JSON HERE*/
var listDataGroups = {}

for(var i=0;i<jsonData.listData.length;i++){
    var letter = jsonData.listData[i].name.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() // get first character and put it to uppercase

    if(!listDataGroups[letter]) // check if no sub-array for that letter exists
        listDataGroups[letter] = [] // in that case create a new sub-array

    listDataGroups[letter].push(jsonData.listData[i]) // push the current element of listData into the sub-array
}
```

Now listDataGroups' structure basically looks like the way you want to display it.

To turn that into html, iterate through the listDataGroups array and create a html string, kind of like this:

```
var html = ''
for(var letter in listDataGroups){
    html += '<div>' // create container div
    html += '<div class="letter-big">'+letter+'</div>' // create div for big letter
    html += '<div class="names-list">'; // create div for name list
    for(var i=0;i<listDataGroups[letter].length;i++){
        html += listDataGroups[letter][i].name + '<br>' //  write out names for this letter
    }
    html += '</div>'
    html += '</div>'
}
```

Then place the html in your DOM where you want it and apply css styles.